Ubuntu 20.04 wifi is not stable
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and my wifi is not stable. It returns error messages with sudo dmesg | grep iwl


The error messages are not related to the stability of your card, rather they're just indicating that certain firmwares were attempted and didn't work as it cycled through available microcode.  When you say "not stable", what do you mean?  Slow? Disconnects? We need more information from you

Was your laptop made during the last two or three years? In that case, a recent version of Ubuntu, like 24.04 would support it better

@ThomasWard I meant it disconnected for a few seconds or one miniute, then reconnects. Not sure how to use cmd to verify the exact problem though.

@ArchismanPanigrahi The desktop was made in 2020 I believe, it was during the pandemic. Not sure if I need to upgrade the whole system.
